# Analyze code with Lint for calls that require permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, lint

I am setting my targetSdkVersion to 23 and therefore I want to implement
"Requesting permissions at runtime". (see [here](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))

Lint directly calls out if you forget to check the permission and 
tells you the following:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
>   explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
>   `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential
>   `SecurityException'

This is quite nice and I want to analyze my code for any call that I may
have forgotten, but I can't find Lint option that I have to select 
in my Inspection profile.

How is the inspection called? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First click on Hector the Inspector (the small icon of a man with a moustache at the very bottom-right of Android Studio). This will bring up an option to Configure inspections.

You should then type **'Permissions'** into the searchbar, and ensure that **"Constant and Resource Type Mismatches"** is checked. After that, it's a simple case of running an inspection via Analyse > Inspect Code.

Comment: Perfect! How could I oversee this inspection. I just looked into "lint", not android. Thanks!

Comment: How can this be achieved not using Android Studio?

Comment: @Maria lint is a part of android tools from sdk

Comment: Can't find Constant and Resource Type Mismatches in android studio 3.1

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO there is Missing Permissions option :)